# How to get mean square from two tensors?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have 2 tensors of shape `(10, 100, 2)`
How do I get the mean square loss of shape `(10, 100)`?

Here is what I have tried:

`tf.sqrt(tf.square(tf.subtract(targets, logits))/n)` which returns `(10, 100, 2)`

Comment: Why am I downvoted? I'm sure a lot of people have the same question.

Comment: `losses = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.map_fn(lambda y: tf.nn.l2_loss(y), x), tf.subtract(targets, logits))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `axis` parameter of `tf.reduce_mean`:

```
x = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sqrt(tf.subtract(targets, logits)), axis=2)
```

x.shape = (10,100)

Answer (score 0):

```
losses = tf.map_fn(
                  lambda x: tf.map_fn(
                      lambda y: tf.nn.l2_loss(y),
                      x
                  ), 
                  tf.subtract(targets, logits)
         )
```

This implements the formula for Mean Square: l2_loss(targets - logits)